# Sometimes after click on submit WebDriver switches to defaultContext instead of current frame

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Test completes locally without fails.
But If I run test in browserstack it fails with message:
`OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException : no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"btnSave"}`

Structure:

```
<frameset id="frameContainer">
   <frame src="menu.html" name="menu"/>
   <frame name="main" src="main_page.html" />
</frameset>
```

I found, if test fails then driver is switched to defualtContext frame. If test completes without fails then driver stay in frame where submit button was clicked.

Chromedriver=84.0.4147.30

Comment: That sounds like you have magic gnomes running your tests, instead of reliable code. Read [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: Ok. My questions is 
How chromedriver determine current frame after pageload?